# Can a front-end React app and back-end Express app share code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

Traditionally I've built web apps with a React/Typescript front-end and a Python back-end.  But I'm experimenting with using ExpressJS/Typescript on the back-end.  So far it's working really well.

Today I built a little helper function to test if a string was a valid email address.  I actually want to use this function on both the front-end and back-end.

Is it possible to have a "common" module of sorts that both the front-end project and back-end project could call?  My team at work does this with Python microservices calling such common functions and types so I'm wondering if this is possible with such an all Typescript application?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyways your react app will be build to a single html and few js files, so module sharing won't be possible unless you host your modules as libraries

Comment: @Kaneki21 - It's definitely possible. I've done it with nested projects, and with symlinks (manual and via `npm link`). (Naturally, you end up with two copies of the result -- one for the server and one for the client. But the source code is shared.) I haven't been happy with any of them. Nested projects (both projects as subprojects of a parent) worked fairly well but didn't play well with auto-deploy in hosting providers. I'm hoping to see The One Obvious Way I've missed. :-D

Comment: Of course it's possible. You just need to structure the project files so it's a monorepo that contains both the front-end and back-end code. You can structure source directories like, src/backend, src/frontend, src/common

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk you are telling that the build files would be able to access the modules if we structure the repo properly ?

Comment: @Kaneki21 op probably meant to share the code when developing, not to share the build.

Comment: (Earlier I said *"Nested projects (both projects as subprojects of a parent) worked fairly well but didn't play well with auto-deploy in hosting providers."* Sorry, that was me misremembering. It worked fine with that. It didn't work with using ESM in Node.js for reasons that I sadly don't recall.)